# Use Wildcards in Replace Function in combination with 2D Array Values

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, replace, wildcard

I'm trying to go through a list with two columns and replace some of the text in the second column. I want to search for values using wildcards in combination with a value inside a 2D Array.

I've a file with all Pokemon cards separated in different worksheets by the set they're in. There are two columns that are called "Name" and "German Name".

I created another worksheet that contains all cards and their corresponding name and German name. Out of that worksheet, I create a 2 dimensional Array. This works.

Then I've loops going on and inside that I've got this line of code.

```vb
Worksheets(table).Cells(otherI, 2).Value = Replace(Worksheets(table).Cells(otherI, 2).Value, " * " & allArray(i, 0) & " * ", " * " & allArray(i, 1) & " * ")
```

Somewhere there is the problem.

E.g. I've the entry "Bulbasaur Lv.5" in both columns and now I want to replace "Bulbasaur" in the second column with its German equivalent "Bisasam" but the "Lv.5" mustn't be touched.

The whole script.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub firstMakro()

'Variables
Dim allSize As Integer
Dim allArray()
Dim allI As Integer
allI = 1

Dim otherSize As Integer
Dim otherI As Integer
otherI = 1

Dim i As Integer
Dim table As Integer
table = 2

'Create Array
allSize = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Worksheets("All_Pokemons").Columns(1))
ReDim allArray(allI To allSize, 1)

Do
    allArray(allI, 0) = Worksheets("All_Pokemons").Cells(allI, 1).Value
    allArray(allI, 1) = Worksheets("All_Pokemons").Cells(allI, 2).Value
    allI = allI + 1
Loop Until allI > allSize
MsgBox ("Array created")

'Replace Entries
For i = LBound(allArray, 1) To UBound(allArray, 1)
    MsgBox (allArray(i, 0))
    otherSize = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Worksheets(table).Columns(1))
    Do
        Worksheets(table).Cells(otherI, 2).Value = Replace(Worksheets(table).Cells(otherI, 2).Value, " * " & allArray(i, 0) & " * ", " * " & allArray(i, 1) & " * ")
        otherI = otherI + 1
    Loop Until otherI > otherSize
    otherI = 1
Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

`Replace` doesn't use, or in this case even need, wildcards.  Use

```vb
Replace(Worksheets(table).Cells(otherI, 2).Value, allArray(i, 0), allArray(i, 1))
```

Answer (score 0):

### Range Replace

- [`Range.Replace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.replace) (Microsoft Docs)
- Tested only on a small dataset (feedback on efficiency (speed) is appreciated).
- It will replace each occurrence of an English name with the associated German name in the whole destination range.
- Adjust the values in the constants section.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Germanize()
    
    Const sName As String = "All_Pokemons"
    Const sfRow As Long = 2 ' ??? First Row
    Const seCol As String = "A" ' ENG
    Const sgCol As String = "B" ' GER
    
    Const dName As String = "Sheet2" ' ??? Worksheet Tab Name
    Const dfRow As Long = 2 ' ??? First Row
    Const deCol As String = "A" ' ENG
    Const dgCol As String = "B" ' GER
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    ' Source (All)
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Worksheets(sName)
    Dim serg As Range: Set serg = RefColumn(sws.Cells(sfRow, seCol)) ' ENG
    If serg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub ' no data
    Dim seData As Variant: seData = GetRange(serg) ' ENG
    Dim sgrg As Range: Set sgrg = serg.EntireRow.Columns(sgCol) ' GER
    Dim sgData As Variant: sgData = GetRange(sgrg) ' GER
    
    ' Destination
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Worksheets(dName)
    Dim derg As Range: Set derg = RefColumn(dws.Cells(dfRow, deCol)) ' ENG
    If derg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub ' no data
    Dim dgrg As Range: Set dgrg = derg.EntireRow.Columns(dgCol) ' GER
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    dgrg.Value = derg.Value ' write ENG column to GER column
    
    Dim seValue As Variant
    Dim r As Long
    
    ' Replace in GER column.
    For r = 1 To UBound(seData, 1)
        seValue = seData(r, 1)
        If Not IsError(seValue) Then
            If Len(seValue) > 0 Then
                dgrg.Replace seValue, CStr(sgData(r, 1)), xlPart, , False
            End If
        End If
    Next r
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
 
    MsgBox "German pokemon names updated.", vbInformation
    
End Sub

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Purpose:      Creates a reference to the one-column range from the first cell
'               of a range ('FirstCell') to the bottom-most non-empty cell
'               of the first cell's worksheet column.
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Function RefColumn( _
    ByVal FirstCell As Range) _
As Range
    Const ProcName As String = "RefColumn"
    On Error GoTo ClearError
    
    With FirstCell.Cells(1)
        Dim lCell As Range
        Set lCell = .Resize(.Worksheet.Rows.Count - .Row + 1) _
            .Find("*", , xlFormulas, , , xlPrevious)
        If lCell Is Nothing Then Exit Function
        Set RefColumn = .Resize(lCell.Row - .Row + 1)
    End With

ProcExit:
    Exit Function
ClearError:
    Debug.Print "'" & ProcName & "' Run-time error '" _
        & Err.Number & "':" & vbLf & "    " & Err.Description
    Resume ProcExit
End Function

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Purpose:      Returns the values of a range ('rg') in a 2D one-based array.
' Remarks:      If ˙rg` refers to a multi-range, only its first area
'               is considered.
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Function GetRange( _
    ByVal rg As Range) _
As Variant
    Const ProcName As String = "GetRange"
    On Error GoTo ClearError
    
    If rg.Rows.Count + rg.Columns.Count = 2 Then ' one cell
        Dim Data As Variant: ReDim Data(1 To 1, 1 To 1): Data(1, 1) = rg.Value
        GetRange = Data
    Else ' multiple cells
        GetRange = rg.Value
    End If

ProcExit:
    Exit Function
ClearError:
    Debug.Print "'" & ProcName & "' Run-time error '" _
        & Err.Number & "':" & vbLf & "    " & Err.Description
    Resume ProcExit
End Function
```